# Parse sentences with different word types

Tags: antlr, whitespace, grammar, words, sentence

I'm looking for a grammar for analyzing two type of sentences, that
means words separated by white spaces:

1. ID1: sentences with words not beginning with numbers
2. ID2: sentences with words not beginning with numbers and numbers

Basically, the structure of the grammar should look like

```
ID1 separator ID2  

ID1: Word can contain number like Var1234 but not start with a number  

ID2: Same as above but 1234 is allowed  

separator: e. g. '='
```

@Bart
I just tried to add two tokens `'_'` and `'"'` as lexer-rule `Special` for later use in lexer-rule `Word`.
Even I haven't used `Special` in the following grammar, I get the following error in ANTLRWorks 1.4.2:
*The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: Special*
But when I add **`fragment`** before `Special`, I don't get that error. Why?

```
grammar Sentence1b1;

tokens
{
  TCUnderscore  = '_' ;
  TCQuote       = '"' ;
}

assignment
  :  id1 '=' id2
  ;

id1
  :  Word+
  ;

id2
  :  ( Word | Int )+
  ;

Int
  :  Digit+
  ;

// A word must start with a letter
Word
  :  ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | Digit )*
  ;

Special
  : ( TCUnderscore | TCQuote )
  ;

Space
  :  ( ' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' ) { $channel = HIDDEN; }
  ;

fragment Digit
  :  '0'..'9'
  ;
```

Lexer-rule `Special` shall then be used in lexer-rule `Word`:

```
Word
  :  ( 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | Special ) ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | Special | Digit )*
  ;
```

Comment: Your definitions of the two different types of sentences could be interpreted in a couple of ways (and you only mean 1 specific way, I assume :)). Could you give some concrete examples of the two types of sentences? Thanks!

Comment: you can edit your original question with new information. I wouldn't post HTML though, have a look at the [Markdown help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to see how to properly format the question.

Comment: Thanks Bart, additional question in my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for something like this:

```
grammar Sentence;

assignment
  :  id1 '=' id2
  ;

id1
  :  Word+
  ;

id2
  :  (Word | Int)+
  ;

Int
  :  Digit+
  ;

// A word must start with a letter
Word
  :  ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | Digit)*
  ;

Space
  :  (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n') {skip();}
  ;

fragment Digit
  :  '0'..'9'
  ;
```

which will parse the input:

> Word can contain number like Var1234 but not start with a number = Same as above but 1234 is allowed

as follows:

[image]

### EDIT

To keep lexer rule nicely packed together, I'd keep them all at the bottom of the grammar instead of partly in the `tokens { ... }` block, which I only use for defining "imaginary tokens" (used in AST creation):

```
// wrong!
Special      : (TCUnderscore | TCQuote);
TCUnderscore : '_';
TCQuote      : '"';
```

Now, with the rules above, `TCUnderscore` and `TCQuote` can never become a token because when the lexer stumbles upon a `_` or `"`, a `Special` token is created. Or in this case:

```
// wrong!
TCUnderscore : '_';
TCQuote      : '"';
Special      : (TCUnderscore | TCQuote);
```

the `Special` token can never be created because the lexer would first create `TCUnderscore` and `TCQuote` tokens. Hence the error:

```
The following token definitions can never be matched because prior tokens match the same input: ...
```

If you make `TCUnderscore` and `TCQuote` a `fragment` rule, you don't have that problem because `fragment` rules only "serve" other lexer rules. So this works:

```
// good!
Special               : (TCUnderscore | TCQuote);
fragment TCUnderscore : '_';
fragment TCQuote      : '"';
```

Also, `fragment` rules can therefor never be "visible" in any of your parser rules (the lexer will never create a `TCUnderscore` or `TCQuote` token!).

```
// wrong!
parse : TCUnderscore;

Special               : (TCUnderscore | TCQuote);
fragment TCUnderscore : '_';
fragment TCQuote      : '"';
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that fits your needs but with Bart's help in my post 
[ANTLR - identifier with whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847971/antlr-identifier-with-whitespace/6850257#6850257) 
i came to this grammar:

```
grammar PropertyAssignment;

assignment
    : id_nodigitstart '=' id_digitstart EOF
    ;

id_nodigitstart
    :   ID_NODIGITSTART+
    ;

id_digitstart
    :   (ID_DIGITSTART|ID_NODIGITSTART)+
    ;

ID_NODIGITSTART
    :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z'|'0'..'9')*
    ;           

ID_DIGITSTART
    :   ('0'..'9'|'a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+
    ;

WS  :   (' ')+ {skip();}
    ;
```

"a name = my 4value" works while "4a name = my 4value" causes an exception.

Comment: Where is the **EOF** defined?

Comment: @ANTLRStarter, `EOF` is a built-in token (which stands for the end-of-file).